# Register stylesheet from web control on page with UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, css, user-controls, stylesheet, web-controls

What is the best method to register a stylesheet once on a page from a customer web control? Please keep in mind that the page uses an UpdatePanel for async calls. I tried just putting the `<link>` tag in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(), but I get this error:

> The script tag registered for type
>   'MyControl'
>   and key 'MyKey' has invalid
>   characters outside of the script tags:
>   . Only properly formatted script tags
>   can be registered.

If I try to add it to the page by adding it to the control hierarchy, it shows up once for each instance of my control on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's what I went with. I decided to create extension methods that will include the link.

**Update:** I had to change the ScriptManager extension as it still was not playing nice with UpdatePanels. Updated code is below.

```
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub RegisterStylesheetInclude(ByVal scriptManager As ScriptManager, ByVal page As Page, ByVal url As String)
        Dim css = "var cssNode = document.createElement('link');" & _
         "cssNode.type = 'text/css';" & _
         "cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';" & _
         "cssNode.href = '" & url & "';" & _
         "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssNode);"

        scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), url, css, True)
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub RegisterStylesheetInclude(ByVal clientScriptManager As ClientScriptManager, ByVal page As Page, ByVal url As String)
        Dim found = page.Header.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlLink).Any(Function(m) m.Href = url)

        If Not found Then
            Dim link As New HtmlLink()
            link.Href = url
            link.Attributes("type") = "text/css"
            link.Attributes("rel") = "stylesheet"
            page.Header.Controls.Add(link)
        End If
    End Sub
```